# Error when calling VideoWriter.getBackendName()

Tags: kotlin, opencv

This is my code

```
class VideoWriterTest {
    @Test
    fun write() {
        OpenCV.loadLocally()
        println("opencv version=${Core.getVersionString()}")

        val fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('a', 'c', 'v', '1')
        val size1 = Size(100.0, 100.0)
        val outputFile= File("temp.mp4")
        outputFile.delete()
        val writer = VideoWriter(outputFile.path, fourcc, 30.0, size1)
        println( writer.backendName)
        assertTrue(writer.isOpened)
    }
}
```

When run, I am getting this error.

```
opencv version=4.6.0

cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.6.0) /home/runner/work/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.6.0/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp:666: error: (-215:Assertion failed) api != 0 in function 'getBackendName'

CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.6.0) /home/runner/work/opencv/opencv/opencv-4.6.0/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp:666: error: (-215:Assertion failed) api != 0 in function 'getBackendName'
]
    at app//org.opencv.videoio.VideoWriter.getBackendName_0(Native Method)
    at app//org.opencv.videoio.VideoWriter.getBackendName(VideoWriter.java:380)
    at app//com.katalisindonesia.heavi.analytic.service.VideoWriterTest.write(VideoWriterTest.kt:26)
```

I use `org.openpnp:opencv:4.6.0-0`.
Any ideas?

EDIT: This code works on macOS but does not work in linux.

EDIT2: Output in macOS

```
opencv version=4.6.0
AVFOUNDATION
```

Comment: Try if it still happens with 4.7.0 and if so, then file a bug report on OpenCV's Github.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to this

```
class VideoWriterTest {
    @Test
    fun write() {
        OpenCV.loadLocally()
        println("opencv version=${Core.getVersionString()}")

        for (i in 0..2400) {
            if (Videoio.hasBackend(i)) {
                println("hasBackend $i")
            }
            if (Videoio.isBackendBuiltIn(i)) {
                println("hasBackendBuiltIn $i")
            }
        }

        val fourcc = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
        val size1 = Size(100.0, 100.0)
        val outputFile = File("temp.avi")
        outputFile.delete()
        val writer = VideoWriter(outputFile.path, Videoio.CAP_OPENCV_MJPEG, fourcc, 30.0, size1)
        assertTrue(writer.isOpened)
    }
}
```

and it passes.

Output:

```
opencv version=4.6.0
hasBackend 200
hasBackendBuiltIn 200
hasBackend 2000
hasBackendBuiltIn 2000
hasBackend 2200
hasBackendBuiltIn 2200
```

Conclusions:

1. openpnp does not bundle ffmpeg
2. fourcc must be in uppercase MJPG. It fails when I use lower case.
3. file name must use `.avi` extension